# Date Range Limitations SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, where-clause

I am wanting to limit the user to not be able to search for a time frame longer than a year. So `1/1/2014` to `1/1/2015` is valid, but `1/1/2014` to `3/1/2015` is not valid. They are inputting the dates in a date picker in a SSRS report.

```
WHERE "view"."myDate" between @firstDate and @secondDate
```

Is there logic I can put in the `WHERE` cause that can put these restrictions into affect?

Answer (score 4):

You could add a [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx) check to the WHERE clause to limit the range to a year;

```
AND DATEDIFF(d, @firstDate, @secondDate) < 366
```

However, this will return nothing if the range exceeds a year. If you want the query to return upto a years worth of results then you could use something like this;

```
WHERE "view"."myDate" between @firstDate and 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @firstDate, @secondDate) < 366 THEN @secondDate 
        ELSE DATEADD(d, 365, @firstDate) 
    END
```

If you want to raise an error if the user provides an invalid range then you would have to use a stored procedure for your data source and perform parameter validation. Something like this;

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetMyData ( @firstDate date, @secondDate ) AS
BEGIN

    IF (DATEDIFF(d, @firstDate, @secondDate) > 365)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Please restrict searches to less than a year.', 16, 1)
        RETURN
    END

    SELECT ...
    WHERE "view"."myDate" between @firstDate and @secondDate

END
```